# PostgreSQL rename table named with a keyword

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named *import*.

I want to rename the table with the following statement in a sql script below.

Unfortunately I can't, because sql treats the term *import* as a psql keyword.

How can I change the name in a sql script?

I have a Database change management also called database migration or database upgrading. Database change management is the process of managing the change of a database over the course of an application's lifecycle. What could change in a database? The database structure (i.e. the tables), master data but even indices, triggers and stored procedures could be added, changed or deleted over time.

```
ALTER TABLE import
RENAME TO api_exchange;
```

I am aware I can change the table name with a PostgreSQL client, but I need to do it in a SQL script for postgreSQL 10 in order to keep my Database change management intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quote reserved words using **double** quotes:

---

```
-- \i tmp.sql

CREATE  TABLE "select"(id integer);

ALTER TABLE "select"
RENAME TO api_exchange;

\d api_exchange
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to change the existing table with the name *import* to *api_exchange*? I created the table with the following statement: `CREATE  TABLE import;`

Comment: I probably need to create a new table *api_exchange* and copy the values of the table *import* to the new table *api_exchange* in order to keep the Database change management intact.

Comment: Yes, of course. (it is *just* a name)  I changed it to`select` because `import` does not appear to be a reserved keyword, so I could not test it using`import`.

Comment: Ok, import is a keyword for postgreSQL 10: [keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Comment: Yes, it is, but it is non-reserved (in Postgres) But it won't harm to quote it anyway.